# Is there a practical use for the additional DOM subcategories in Devtools > Elements > Properties?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools

Like everyone else I use Chrome DevTools to inspect an HTML Element's properties.  For example if I needed to know which properties were attached to a specific `<DIV>` I would do this.

1. Go to DevTools
2. Open the Elements panel
3. Click the HTML DIV element I wanted to inspect
4. In the right panel click the Properties tab
5. The top listing will be div.(classname)
6. Click that label and view the properties

Awesome!  I can see all of the properties attached to that node and use them as needed.

But below that are 6 additional listings that I and possibly a lot of other people never use.  They appear to represent part of the [DOM hierarchy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement).

- HTMLDivElement
- HTMLElement
- Element
- Node
- EventTarget
- Object

**Question:** Do these also have a practical use when building a site?  Am I missing out on something cool that I could use them for?  Are they merely there for reference?  Thanks for any input!

Comment: I removed the `devtools` tag, as it is about R, not about the web.

Comment: that's the inheritance chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of object and interface types and contrary to your assertion that not a lot of people use them. They are extensively used (although you may not even realize it).

- Object

In JavaScript, everything is an `Object`. Objects are endowed with basic properties and methods and literally every other object inherits these.

- EventTarget

Is specific reference to the object that was the source for an event being triggered.

- Node

In the W3C Document Object Model API (nice overview **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)**), specific element types are not what is paramount. All elements and attributes (as well as other types of markup, such as DOCTYPE and comments) are generically referred to as "nodes" and every node has certain properties (i.e. `nodeName`, `nodeType`, `nodeValue` and methods). The DOM API favors treating all markup as fundamental nodes. This API is designed this way because it works with HTML but also XML.

- Element

Is a generic term used to talk about any HTML element.

- HTMLElement

Is an "interface" that describes the various ways you can programatically interact with any object that implements the interface (as all HTML elements do).

- HTMLDivElement

Is a more specific interface that describes what an HTML `DIV` element should expose for programattic interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused between tag names, like `<div>` and [DOM interfaces](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-dom) such as 'HTMLDivElement`. The first is part of creating a document structure and the second is an interface for the browser and scripting.

> The HTMLDivElement **interface provides special properties** (beyond the
>   regular HTMLElement interface it also has available to it by
>   inheritance) for manipulating div elements.

Search through MDN or [the spec itself](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/) and carefully read those descriptions of the others in your list.